# Saving some info into application resource and read it from anywhere

Tags: c#, resources

Im wonder, is it possible, to save something in a field in output (exe) application file?
For example if i want to save somewhere (but not in database) date when application had first start, and then after couple days check value when was first start?

Thanks.

Comment: there are several options question is are you the only one that will be launching the application..? you could write to EventLog, you could store the value in a Log File , Settings, etc.....

Answer (score 2):

There are many options but do take a look at [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (also a [newer set of articles here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

This is a good way to persist simple data such as your example of first application start date/time w/o the need for a db or some other, "heavier", persistence scheme.

From the linked article:

> The .NET Framework ... allows you to create and access values that are
>   persisted between application execution sessions. These values are
>   called settings. Settings can represent user preferences, or valuable
>   information the application needs to use. For example, you might
>   create a series of settings that store user preferences for the color
>   scheme of an application. Or you might store the connection string
>   that specifies a database that your application uses. Settings allow
>   you to both persist information that is critical to the application
>   outside of the code, and to create profiles that store the preferences
>   of individual users.

Comment: Ok, i found something like Properties.Settings.Default[...] and im saving there date of first start. but question is actually that - if i want to create application only for 1 day (for example) as demo, is it good way to check date from setting_1 - date from setting_2 and disable access to application? is there any possibility that somebody will hack it and change .settings ?

Comment: Yes, those are the Settings API I am referring to. But no matter where you save those values on a client's computer *they can be hacked*. Properties.Settings.Default is as good a place as any. A small measure of "security improvement" would be to obfuscate the names and you can also encrypt the data to hide it further. Note that this isn't hack proof either. Nothing is.